# Creating map collection to find words occurrence in text and sum them

Tags: java

I have text (that can be changed from time to time )that I need to pass in the main argument and
I need to create Map collection to count the put the word and the 
number of the occurrence for instance.

```
aaa bbb cccc aaaa

Result 
(aaa,2
bbb,1
ccc,1
....
```

What is the best way to do that in map collection?

I saw few example of **Multiset** but I want to know how I can do that in **Map** **collection.**

I have tried with the following code but I don't see the words and the occurrence number 
in counter

```
    for(String Text:args){
        System.out.println(Text);

        String[] words=Text.split(" ");

        HashMap<String,Integer> counter=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for (String w: Arrays.asList(Text)){
          Integer num=counter.get(w);
          if (num!=null)
              counter.put(w,num+1);
          else
              counter.put(w,1);
        }   

    }
```

Comment: I would suggest searching here at Stack Overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139633/word-frequency-counter

Comment: The best way is to try something yourself, then post a more specific question if you run into any issues.

Comment: I wonder why no-one has ever had this `[homework]` before ;)

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to use a [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) which is meant to count frequencies. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) is the tutorial. You should however depend on a library called [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).